# Python, add dictionary to JSON file

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary, append

I have JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  { 
    "lon": 0.0, 
    "altitude": 39000, 
  }, 
  {
    "lon": 0.0, 
    "altitude": 41000, 
   }
]
```

and I want save this file locally and updates from source file.
For example:
Refreshed source file have new data:

```
[
  { 
    "lon": 19.84227, 
    "altitude": 41000, 
  }, 
  {
    "lon": 20.068794, 
    "altitude": 38000, 
  } 
]
```

how to append local JSON file to add 2 new dictionaries at the end of file to have this:

```
[
  {
     values
  },
  {
     values
  },          <<< add " , " and new part of dictionaries
  {
     values
  },
  {
     values
  }
[
```

I trying append JSON files but I have this:

```
[
 ....
][     << [ and ] must be only at the beggining and end of file
 ....
]
```

how ?

Comment: You can load the json files into 2 python lists, concatenate them and then dump them back to a file.  Of course other formatting/order of the keys in the dicts might be lost (but it will be equivalent as far as JSON is concerned)...

Comment: But the data in files growing extreme fast, in one file I have ex. 60 dictionaries with 10-12 values. File is refreshing every second and after a few minutes file have ~15000 lines!

Comment: You might be able to cache the contents of the JSON file so you don't have to load it every time...but you will need to write it out every time it's updated if it's important that the version on disk always contain all the latest additions.

Comment: There is no need to file on the disk was in the latest version, it can be saved at a time, just to earlier data have not been removed. And that it is possible to interrupt the program and after the resumption of adding new data to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found simple solution:

Append JSON file with new data:

```
import os, json

with open('data.json', 'a') as fp:
    json.dump(j_data, fp, indent = 2)
fp.close()

f = open('data.json','r')
old_data = f.read()
f.close()
```

search " ][ " and replace it with " , "

```
new_data = old_data.replace("][", ",")
```

save as new file

```
f = open('data_new.json','w')
f.write(new_data)
f.close()
```

remove old file and rename new file

```
os.remove('data.json')
os.rename('data_new.json', 'data.json')
```